# Python Get the URL of all posts of an Instagram user

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, instagram, screen-scraping

I have written a small piece of code to download images from Instagram. Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as req
import urllib.request as reqq
from selenium import webdriver
import os


browser = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Python_Files\\Programs\\chromedriver.exe")

url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CFRY7X2AnOx/"

browser.get(url)
image_url = browser.find_element_by_class_name('KL4Bh').find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src')

reqq.urlretrieve(image_url,"D:\\instaimg.jpg")
```

This works fine. But this can only download one image. Is there any way to get the URL of all the posts of a user so that all images posted by the user can be downloaded?

Comment: The link you've used directs to a single post by the person. Wouldn't it be better to go the profile first and THEN get all post's images?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The question you've asked is too broad. Do you want all images from every post or just the first image? What about videos they've posted?

Comment: I have actually modified my code so that both images and videos can be downloaded. That is not a prob now. I just want to get the link of all the posts made by the user.

Comment: I think that I have got it. The URL of all posts are there under the div tag of class "v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w" Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
browser.get("https://instagram.com/"+username)

# Click on the first post
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[3]/article/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a").click()

# Wait a second or two for the post to load using either the `time` module or whatever way you want

posts = []
while True:
    try:
        posts.append(browser.current_url)
        arrow = browser.find_element_by_class_name("coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow")
        arrow.click()
    except:
        # Arrow was not found, so you must be on the last post
        break

print(posts)
```